# Delete part of the data in SAS

Tags: split, sas, conditional-statements

I have a dataset called a, I want to delete the rows that column with the name "AVG_OPT_PR" = '.' And the following code works:

```
DATA work.a1;
  SET work.a;
    IF AVG_OPT_PR = '.' THEN delete;
RUN;
```

However, there is another column called "Period", and I just want to delete the rows that within one Location, all "AVG_OPT_PR" = '.'. How can I do that?

For example, data looks like:

```
Location_id |     Period  | AVG_OPT_PR 
------------+-------------+-----------
   L_1      | 2 weeks     |  105 
   L_1      | 1 month     |   .
   ...      |    ...      |  ... 
   L_1      | 1  year     |  103 
   L_2      | 2 weeks     |   . 
   L_2      | 1 month     |   . 
   ...      |    ...      |  ... 
   L_2      | 1 year      |   .
```

Hence, rows that location id equals "L_2" are deleted, but all data for "L_1" are kept.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Select the maximum value of `avg_opt_pr` for each `location_id` (if the max is missing, it will come out as .), merge it back onto the first dataset, then drop all the `location_ids` that have a max of missing.

```
proc sql;
    create table a2 as select distinct
        location_id, max(avg_opt_pr) as avg_opt_pr_max
        from a1
        group by location_id;
quit;

proc sql;
    create table a3 as select
        a.*, b.avg_opt_pr_max
        from a1 as a
        left join a2 as b
        on a.location_id = b.location_id;
    delete from a3 where missing(avg_opt_pr_max);
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks! I get your logic. The first part is great when generating table a2, while I tried to run it, the log file says: Column location_id cannot be found in the correlation name in a.

Comment: I used "a1" because your example used "work.a1" as your sample dataset. If you're not pulling from that dataset, replace "a1" with the dataset you're actually pulling from.

Comment: I also replaced when coming across the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's as simple as wanting to only delete rows with both an `AVG_OPT_PR` of `.` and a `Location_id` of `L-2`, then this should work just fine.

```
DATA work.a1;
  SET work.a;
    IF AVG_OPT_PR = '.' and Location_id = 'L_2' THEN delete;
RUN;
```

And some additional examples to expand on how you could handle this with the `IF THEN DELETE`

To delete all rows with `AVG_OPT_PR` of `.` and where its `Location_id` does *not* equal `L_1` (so everything but `L_1`)

```
DATA work.a1;
  SET work.a;
    IF AVG_OPT_PR = '.' and Location_id ^= 'L_1' THEN delete;
RUN;
```

And to delete all rows with `AVG_OPT_PR` of `.` and where its `Location_id` is one of those listed `IN ('L_2','L_3','L_4',...)`

```
DATA work.a1;
  SET work.a;
    IF AVG_OPT_PR = '.' and Location_id IN ('L_2','L_3','L_4') THEN delete;
RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks! In this way it works, but how to make it in general? Ex, there are a lot of Location_id ?

Comment: @CrubalChenxiLi Added some further examples for how to handle it the way you're currently doing it. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! In my case, there are more than 4000 location_id, can I write something other than "and Location_id IN ('L_2','L_3','L_4', ...)" ?

Comment: @CrubalChenxiLi If there's some logic behind which `Location_id`s you're keeping and deleting, there would probably be a better way than just listing the ones to delete. Otherwise, you could use `NOT IN` to do the opposite (list the locations to keep) if that list is shorter than which to delete.

Comment: Thanks! I will figure out.